# Splitting a data frame in rows according to a pattern in a column

Tags: r, regex, dataframe

i have a data frame like so;

```
mydf=data.frame(Authors=c("A","B","C"), ID=c("1","2","3"), Adresses=c("[XYZ, DEF] Ege Univ, Izmir, Turkey","[Vil, Beat; Fern, Alm; Pro-Pas, Ram; Fevfz, Jes; Saur, Mari] INIA CSIC, Dept Genet Anim, Madrid, Spain; [Penza, Carna; Housen, Rosie] Univ Edigh, Roxbn Inst, Edinburgh, Scotland","[Zeek, Umt] Kastamonu Univ, Kast, Turkey; [Kalu, Sear] Ege Univ, Fac Engn, Izmir, Turkey"))
```

it seems like this:

[image: data frame before]

i want to split it according to pattern in `Adresses` column like this:

[image]

Here the pattern is something like this: [ ] ;
But the last record of the cell (or if the cell has only one record ) doesn't have a semicolon as you can see from the first picture.

i tried with `tidyr`, `dplyr`, `regex` in r and also this `strsplit(as.character(mydf[,3]), "[[(.*)]](.*);")` pattern but it didn't work. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `base R`, we can split the column into a `list` of vectors and then `rep`licate the rows of the data based on the `lengths` of the `list` and update the 'Adresses' by `unlist`ing the `list`

```
lst1 <- strsplit(mydf$Adresses, ";\\s*(?=\\[)", perl = TRUE)
mydf2 <-  transform(mydf[rep(seq_len(nrow(mydf)), lengths(lst1)),],
    Adresses = unlist(lst1))
row.names(mydf2) <- NULL
```

-output

```
> mydf2
  Authors ID                                                                                               Adresses
1       A  1                                                                     [XYZ, DEF] Ege Univ, Izmir, Turkey
2       B  2 [Vil, Beat; Fern, Alm; Pro-Pas, Ram; Fevfz, Jes; Saur, Mari] INIA CSIC, Dept Genet Anim, Madrid, Spain
3       B  2                              [Penza, Carna; Housen, Rosie] Univ Edigh, Roxbn Inst, Edinburgh, Scotland
4       C  3                                                               [Zeek, Umt] Kastamonu Univ, Kast, Turkey
5       C  3                                                         [Kalu, Sear] Ege Univ, Fac Engn, Izmir, Turkey
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `; (?=\\[)`-regex, looking for a semi-colon and a space before a bracket.

E.g. with `tidyr`:

```r
library(tidyr)

mydf |>
  separate_rows(Adresses, sep = "; (?=\\[)")
```

Output:

```r
# A tibble: 5 × 3
  Authors ID    Adresses                                                                                              
  <chr>   <chr> <chr>                                                                                                 
1 A       1     [XYZ, DEF] Ege Univ, Izmir, Turkey                                                                    
2 B       2     [Vil, Beat; Fern, Alm; Pro-Pas, Ram; Fevfz, Jes; Saur, Mari] INIA CSIC, Dept Genet Anim, Madrid, Spain
3 B       2     [Penza, Carna; Housen, Rosie] Univ Edigh, Roxbn Inst, Edinburgh, Scotland                             
4 C       3     [Zeek, Umt] Kastamonu Univ, Kast, Turkey                                                              
5 C       3     [Kalu, Sear] Ege Univ, Fac Engn, Izmir, Turkey
```

Comment: Hi, this is a neat method! Could you tell me what's the difference between this one and @darren's?

Comment: Hi @user18894435, din't see @Darren's until now. There're almost identical and postet at the same time: Darren is explicitly stating a whitespace-type `\\s`, I state a whitespace ` `. The `*` means zero of more spaces. My code always matches one.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `separate_rows()` and set the separator as `';\\s*(?=\\[)'`:

```r
library(tidyr)

mydf %>%
  separate_rows(Adresses, sep = ';\\s*(?=\\[)')

# # A tibble: 5 × 3
#   Authors ID    Adresses                                                          
#   <chr>   <chr> <chr>                                                             
# 1 A       1     [XYZ, DEF] Ege Univ, Izmir, Turkey                                
# 2 B       2     [Vil, Beat; Fern, Alm; Pro-Pas, Ram; Fevfz, Jes; Saur, Mari] INIA…
# 3 B       2     [Penza, Carna; Housen, Rosie] Univ Edigh, Roxbn Inst, Edinburgh, …
# 4 C       3     [Zeek, Umt] Kastamonu Univ, Kast, Turkey                          
# 5 C       3     [Kalu, Sear] Ege Univ, Fac Engn, Izmir, Turkey
```